# Using OR in filters for Office 365 Service Communications API or filtering by multiple IDs

Tags: office365api

How can I filter by multiple IDs using the Office 365 Service Communications API?

I'm getting the current status using `https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/{tenent}/ServiceComms/CurrentStatus` which gives me incident IDs. I'm trying to use those IDs to get the messages affiliated but the message endpoint `/ServiceComms/Messages` is not working well with the filters.
The documentation shows: [image: ServiceComAPI]

I've tried:

`/ServiceComms/Messages?ID=CR555555`,`/ServiceComms/Messages?ID='CR555555'`, `/ServiceComms/Messages?Id=CR555555`,`/ServiceComms/Messages?Id='CR555555'` - Returns everything (doesn't filter)

`/ServiceComms/Messages?$filter=ID eq 'CR555555'` - Returns Error

`/ServiceComms/Messages?$filter=Id eq 'CR555555'` - Returns 1 result

`/ServiceComms/Messages?$filter=Id eq 'CR555555' or Id eq 'CR555556'` - Returns error

I was able to get an AND result using
`$filter=MessageType eq Microsoft.Office365ServiceComms.ExposedContracts.MessageType'Incident' and EndTime ge 2019-07-25T00:00:00Z` but OR always errors with the message `"Filter {filter} is invalid. Expected '<Item> <operator> <Value>' pattern."`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Microsoft.Office365ServiceComms.ExposedContracts.MessageType'Incident'` as your `MessageType`.

A request to `/Messages` should return you a odata context at the top of the response. For example:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://office365servicecomms-prod.cloudapp.net/api/v1.0/{{TenantID}}/$metadata#Messages",
    ...
}

If you query that, you receive the metadata along with the possible filters. I cannot give you an example as of today (2020-02-16) a query returns a 500 Internal Server Error. Microsoft is working on a fix. Maybe it works again by the time you read my reply.
```

Complete example:
`https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/{{TenantID}}/ServiceComms/Messages?$filter=MessageType eq Microsoft.Office365ServiceComms.ExposedContracts.MessageType'Incident' and LastUpdatedTime ge 2020-02-13T00:00:00.000Z`

And yes, the ID filter must be written 'Id'. Microsofts documentation has a lot of wrong information in it.